# Prevent voice recording during phone calls

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recording

I am working on voice recording functionality. I want to prevent recording during phone call and need to so message **"Can't record voice message during a phone call"** One thing I can do is, I can Read phone state with using Broadcast Receiver while Incoming or Outgoing calls with READ_PHONE_STATE Permission. But it is dangerous permission to put. Is there any alternative way to do this functionality? If I add READ_PHONE_STATE Permission for this functionality then whether Google permit to my app?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can read phone state without the READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Comment: (as an aside: I'd recommend removing the part about whether it will be permitted to avoid your question being closed as off-topic: see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information)

Comment: @RyanM No I am not asking for read phone state without permission.. I am asking for is it better to use phone permission for my functionality? or any alternative to do this..

Comment: Oh, I see.  Hmmm, I don't think so, at least if you want to show a message specific to phone calls.  I'm not 100% sure, though.